# Nginx config for docker php-fpm container: "Access to the script '/xxx/xxx/openapi/index.html' has been denied (see security.limit_extensions)"

Tags: php, docker, nginx

There is swagger openapi generated in php-fpm container I need access to. 
Here is the corresponding location block from nginx default.conf:

```
location /openapi/ {
    alias /xxx/xxx/openapi/;
    fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $request_filename;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

From docker logs of php-fpm container:

```
"GET /openapi/index.html" 403
NOTICE: Access to the script '/xxx/xxx/openapi/index.html' has been denied (see security.limit_extensions)
```

Any advice, please?

Answer (score 0):

Disregard. I just shared openapi location in Dockerfile for php-fpm:

```
VOLUME ["/xxx/xxx"]
```

And then mounted it to container with nginx to serve directly.